# Apache 2.2 (Prefork) + APC issue

Tags: apache2, apc

I have a dedicated server running FreeBSD 7.2 64bit.

When I enable APC on Apache (Prefork), I notice in 'top' and in the SIZE column, it grows from 110MB to 384MB. I realize this is shared memory and shared across all apache processes.

The problem I have is this :

Each process size (in the 'RES" column) grows from 25mb to almost 100mb EACH.

Why does this happen?

My processes never grow any larger than 30mb without APC. I only have 8gb ram so if each apache process takes up 100mb, I have to set my 'MaxClients' to 50 in order for my server not to use swap.

Comment: I just also wanted to add that I'm using : Apache 2.2.15  / PHP 5.3.2  / APC 3.1.3p1

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to adjust the value of apc.shm_size in your php.ini or apc.ini if you are using a separated congig file to load apc